# Get latest Reading value of each type for a Sensor in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

A `Sensor` has many `Reading`s each with a value and type at a timestamp.  I want to create an attribute on `Sensor` that would list the latest value for each type.  I know how I would get this in SQL, but how can I construct it with SQLAlchemy?

```sql
select * from (
    select * from Readings
    left join Sensors on Readings.SensorID = Sensors.SensorID
    where Readings.SensorID = passed_id order by Timestamp desc
) as tmp group by ValueType;
```

```
class Reading(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Readings'
    index = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sensor_id = db.Column('SensorID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Sensors.SensorID'))
    sensor_type = db.Column('SensorType', db.Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column('Timestamp', db.DateTime)
    value_type = db.Column('ValueType', db.Integer)
    value = db.Column('Value', db.Float)

class Sensor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Sensors'
    index = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = db.Column('SensorID', db.Integer, unique=True)
    type = db.Column('SensorType', db.Integer)
    location = db.Column('Location', db.String(50))
    readings = db.relationship('Reading',  backref='SensorID', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've finally found the solution. I added following to the Sensor class:

```
@property
def last_readings(self):
    sub = object_session(self) \
           .query(Reading.value, Reading.value_type.label('value_type')) \
           .filter(Reading.sensor_id == self.id) \
           .order_by(Reading.timestamp.desc()).subquery()
    return object_session(self).query(sub).group_by(sub.c.value_type)
```